# Windows Server 2008R2 running MS Office 2010 - UAC Prompts

Tags: windows-server-2008, microsoft-office

I've got a single terminal server with Office 2010 installed on it with the appropriate license installed. Anytime a new user attempts to use Office for the first time, they are prompted with the option of installing updates automatically, downloading only, or not installing. This requires UAC elevation, which they should not have on this server. Is there any way to prevent things like this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change this setting using the Office 2010 administrative templates and setting a loopback GPO on the container that the terminal server exists in ADUC.

The Office 2010 Administrative Template Files can be found [HERE](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18968)